# Setting file modification date from exif date

Tags: touch, exiftool, filetime

To set the file modification date of images to the exif date, I tried the following: 
`exiftool '-FileModifyDate<DateTimeOriginal' image.jpg`
But this gives me an error about SetFileTime.
So maybe exiftool cannot do it in linux.

Can I combine 
`exiftool -m -p '$FileName - $DateTimeOriginal' -if '$DateTimeOriginal' -DateTimeOriginal -s -S -ext jpg .` with "touch --date ..."?

Answer (score 3):

See [this Exiftool Forum post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php/topic,7198.msg36490.html#msg36490).

The command used there is (take note of the use of backticks, not single quotes):

```
touch -t `exiftool -s -s -s -d "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S" -DateTimeOriginal TEST.JPG` TEST.JPG
```

But I'm curious about your error.  Exiftool should be able to set the FileModifyDate on Linux (though FileCreateDate is a different story).  What version of Exiftool are you using (`exiftool -ver` to check)?

Another possibility is that the `DateTimeOriginal` tag is malformed or doesn't have the full date/time info in it.

Comment: `exiftool test.jpg
/
/ExifTool Version Number         : 10.23
/File Access Date/Time           : 2016:11:06 21:44:15+01:00
/File Permissions                : rwx------
/Modify Date                     : 2015:08:21 18:51:28
/Exif Version                    : 0230
/Date/Time Original              : 2015:08:04 10:00:35
/Create Date                     : 2015:08:04 10:00:35
`

Comment: the reason why exiftool does not work is that the pictures are on a samba share in my NAS.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, StarGeek's answer was a great pointer in the right direction, but it did not work for me: many of my photos were reported to have "Invalid EXIF text encoding" (no obvious difference compared to those that were "fine"), even though `exiftool somefile.jpg` would clearly output a valid "Modify Date".

So this is what I did:

```
for i in *.jpg ; do d=`exiftool $i | grep Modify | sed 's/.*: //g'` ; echo "$i : $d" ; done
```

...to produce output like this:

```
CAM00786.jpg : 2013:11:19 18:47:27
CAM00787.jpg : 2013:11:25 08:46:08
CAM00788.jpg : 2013:11:25 08:46:19
...
```

It was enough for me to output the timestamps next to the file names, but given a little bit of date-time formatting, it could easily be used to "touch" the files to modify their filesystem timestamps.